# Getting Commodity Level in UNSPSC using Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I have got a scenario, where i need to fetch UNSPSC commodity level using regular expression and get level as..

each UNSPSC code is of 8 digit ..

Ist Level  :XX 00 00 00

2nd Level  :XX XX 00 00

3rd Level  :XX XX XX 00

4th Level  :XX XX XX XX.

Is thery any way to get level using Single Regular Expression, I was using, 
((.)+)00 ... for each level match.

Not sure how to do it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex `((.)+)00` matches 1+ times any character followed by `00` which does not take 8 digits into account. For the fourth level you want a match that does not end with `00`.

If you can not have 4 pairs of 2 times a zero, and 2 times a zero can not occur before not 2 times a zero you might use an alternation with capturing groups. Then check in the matcher if group 1, 2 or 3 exists to get level 1, 2 or 3. If there is a match and there is no group, then you will have level 4.

`^(?:(0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])0{6}|(0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]){2}0{4}|((?:0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])){3}00|(?:0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]){4})$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q9zDoD/1/)

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of the string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])0{6}` Match 01-99 followed by 6 times a 0
  - `|` Or
  - `(0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]){2}0{4}` Match 2 times 01-99 followed by 4 times a zero
  - `|` Or
  - `(?:(?:0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])){3}00` Match 3 times 01-99 followed by 2 times a zero
  - `|` Or
  - `(0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]){4})` Match 4 times 01-99
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `$` End of the string

For example:

```
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
        if (null != matcher.group(1)) {
            System.out.println("Level 1");
        } else if (null != matcher.group(2)) {
            System.out.println("Level 2");
        } else if (null != matcher.group(3)) {
            System.out.println("Level 3");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Level 4");
        }   
}
```

Output:

```
Full match: 01000000
Level 1
Full match: 10000000
Level 1
Full match: 99990000
Level 2
Full match: 99999900
Level 3
Full match: 55555555
Level 4
```

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/GzMhKI)

Comment: Actually i dont need space though, just wrote to help in understanding.

Comment: @DeepakDhaka I have updated my answer so that is does not match a space.

Comment: @Th fourth bird, it matches the required syntax, but is it possible to capture, the level count from regex. like, passing the code and getting level using regex.

Comment: @DeepakDhaka I have updated my answer to get the levels.

Comment: For, String line = "15000000";F

ull match: 15000000
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 1
 at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:538)
 at RegexTesting.main(RegexTesting.java:21)
 
Is there anything i did wrong?